# A new ‘Personal Team’ with the role ‘Free’ - IONIC 2 - Deploy ios

Tags: ios, xcode, deployment, ionic2, provisioning-profile

I want to test my ionic app on ios device like iPhone, so I read this [doc](https://ionicframework.com/docs/intro/deploying/)
and I try to create a apple id with the role free, but I get role user! why? how can I test my app on devices in free mode?

**EDITED :**

I got this error :

> cannot create a IOS App Development provisioning profile for 'package
>   name' . Your development team, "team name", does not support the
>   Associated Domains capability.

Comment: That shouldn't matter.  Have you tried finishing the rest of the instructions to run it on a device?

Comment: @wottle yes! I edited the question.